# SVN: How to add new external directory not under version control to existing repository?

Tags: svn

To better ask my question, I need to explain my current setup:

I have a test web environment set up under `/var/www/dev` which I use as a sandbox.
I have an e-commerce app installed under `/var/www/shop` which is set up as an alias for both my sandbox and beta environments.

`/var/www/dev` is under version control, `/var/www/shop` is not.  What I would like to do is to somehow add the shop directory to the dev repository without moving the location of either directories.  Like a symbolic link...

First, is this even possible?  If not, is there a way to "join" repositories so that when I check out or commit to the "main" one, they are both checked out / committed?  Or is there maybe a better way of accomplishing this altogether?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could simply add a symbolic link, however you would then have to either add it to svn or svn:ignore it.

My preference for the symbolic link would be to manage an Alias in the Apache configuration (for example also through svn)

The other solution is to use svn:externals, in this case /var/www/shop has to be in subversion as well of course. The solution would then *not* ensure that /var/www/shop is not moved, however it would achieve the same result, however with the option of checkout out different versions of the "/var/www/shop" code in dev, staging or other environments.

The most modern solution that I highly recommend is to manage such library code with composer.

Comment: I do use composer for things like paypal, symphony, and phpunit.  Not sure how that would work for zen-cart...
And AFAIK, when creating a symbolic link in SVN, it only puts the link itself in the repository, and not the directory to which it is linked.